# Quick Average Speed Question

Tags: calculus, integration, algebra-precalculus, derivatives, definite-integrals

I was studying for a test and found the following prompt (similar to another question that was asked, I just had one question that had a number of different prompts that centered around the main prompt):

"A student programs a robot to move across a flat surface over the time interval $0≤t≤20$  seconds. The position of the robot at time $t$ seconds is given by the parametric equations  $x(t)=3t+\sin(t)$ and $y(t)=3\cos(t−\sin(t))$, where  $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are measured in meters. The derivatives of these functions are given by $x′(t)=3+\cos(t)$ and $y(t)=−3\sin(t-\sin(t))⋅(1−\cos(t))$. Find the average speed of the robot from time $t=0$ seconds to time $t=20$ seconds."

I guess I'm confused about what the integral would look like in this specific context. I've done average speed problems before and I understood what the formulas and set-ups looked like then, but this specific problem seems to be giving me some trouble. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If the answer below doesn't explain it, maybe it would help if you show us the formulas you know.

Answer (score 3):

The instantaneous speed is $s(t)=\sqrt{x'(t)^2+y'(t)^2}$, and the average speed is $\frac{1}{T}\int_0^Ts(t)\,\mathrm d t$, where $T=20 \,\text{s}$.
Does it make sense?

Comment: Ok, looks like I'm coming up with about $3.9$, does that look right to you?

Comment: It looks closer to $4.0$ to me.